# Azure-Data-Factory - If Condition returns false despite being logically true

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to do a logical test to compare two activity outputs.
The first one is giving back a file name (derived from GetMetaData)and the other one distinct filenames that are already in the database (derived from a lookup Activity).

So the first activity is giving X.csv (a file in a Blob0 while the second one is giving a list Y.csv; Z.csv (the result of the lookup Select distinct from table X)
Based on this outcome I would say that the logical test is true so ADF has to start a particular activity. I'm using the expresion below, but despite the fact there are no errors the outcome is always false. What am I doing wrong? I guess it has something to do with the lookup activity because the query will give a list of values I think.

please help thanks in advance!

```
@equals(activity('GetBlobName').output,activity('LookupBestandsnaam').output)
```

Output activity LookupBestandsnaam:

[image: Output activity LookupBestandsnaam]

Output activity GetBlobName:

[image: Output activity GetBlobName]

Comment: The output of two activities clearly shows different keys and values and are expected to only return false unless both are identically equal with same (number & name of) keys and valyes.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I fixed it with a sp in SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of Lookup and Get Metadata are different:

- [Lookup activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) reads and returns the content of a configuration file
  or table.
- [Get Metadata activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity) to retrieve the metadata of any data in Azure
  Data Factory

We can't compare the output directly. You will always get `false` in the if condition expression.

Please try bellow expression:

```
@equals(activity('GetBlobName').output.value.name,activity('LookupBestandsnaam').output.value.bestandsnaam)
```

**Update:**

Congratulations that you use another way to solved it:

"I have now replaced the if condition with a stored procedure that uses an IF exists script running on the basis of look-up activity in ADF."

Comment: Hey Leon,

Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, your proposal did not succeed. I have now replaced the if condition with a stored procedure that uses an IF exists script running on the basis of look-up activity in ADF.

Thanks again!

Best,

Comment: @DickterSchiphorst You're welcome. May I add this to my answer? Then others could know your question resolved now.

Comment: Sure Leon! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DickterSchiphorst You're welcome.  Can you please accept it as answer? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you!